# how to reduce CudaMemcpy Overhead

Tags: memory, cuda, gpu

I have an array of size 3000 the array contains 0 and 1.i want to find first array position that have 1 stored at that location starting from 0th index.i transfer this array to Host and this array is computed on device.then i sequentially computed index on Host.in my program i want to do this computation repeatably 4000 or more times.i want to reduce the time taken by this process.is there any other way by which we can do this and this array is computed on GPU actually so i have to transfer it each time.

```
int main()
{
for(int i=0;i<4000;i++)
{
    cudaMemcpy(A,dev_A,sizeof(int)*3000,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    int k;
    for(k=0;k<3000;k++)
    {
        if(A[k]==1)
        {
            break;
        } 
    }
    printf("got k is %d",k);
}
}
```

Complete code is like this
    #include"cuda.h"
    #include
    #define SIZE 2688
    #define BLOCKS 14
    #define THREADS 192

```
__global__ void kernel(int *A,int *d_pos)
{
int thread_id=threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
while(thread_id<SIZE)
{
    if(A[thread_id]==INT_MIN)
    {
        *d_pos=thread_id;
        return;
    }
    thread_id+=1;   
}
```

}

```
__global__ void kernel1(int *A,int *d_pos)
{
int thread_id=threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
if(A[thread_id]==INT_MIN)
{
    atomicMin(d_pos,thread_id);
}
```

}

```
int main()
{
int pos=INT_MAX,i;
int *d_pos;
int A[SIZE];
int *d_A;
for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
{
    A[i]=78;
}
A[SIZE-1]=INT_MIN;
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_pos,sizeof(int));
cudaMemcpy(d_pos,&pos,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A,sizeof(int)*SIZE);
cudaMemcpy(d_A,A,sizeof(int)*SIZE,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudaEvent_t start_cp1,stop_cp1;
    cudaEventCreate(&stop_cp1);
    cudaEventCreate(&start_cp1);
    cudaEventRecord(start_cp1,0);

kernel1<<<BLOCKS,THREADS>>>(d_A,d_pos);

cudaEventRecord(stop_cp1,0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop_cp1);
    float elapsedTime_cp1;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime_cp1,start_cp1,stop_cp1);
    cudaEventDestroy(start_cp1);
    cudaEventDestroy(stop_cp1);
    printf("\nTime taken by kernel is  %f\n",elapsedTime_cp1);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

cudaEvent_t start_cp,stop_cp;
    cudaEventCreate(&stop_cp);
    cudaEventCreate(&start_cp);
    cudaEventRecord(start_cp,0);

cudaMemcpy(A,d_A,sizeof(int)*SIZE,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaEventRecord(stop_cp,0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop_cp);
    float elapsedTime_cp;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime_cp,start_cp,stop_cp);
    cudaEventDestroy(start_cp);
    cudaEventDestroy(stop_cp);
    printf("\ntime taken by copy of an array is  %f\n",elapsedTime_cp);






    cudaEvent_t start_cp2,stop_cp2;
    cudaEventCreate(&stop_cp2);
    cudaEventCreate(&start_cp2);
    cudaEventRecord(start_cp2,0);

    cudaMemcpy(&pos,d_pos,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaEventRecord(stop_cp2,0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop_cp2);
    float elapsedTime_cp2;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime_cp2,start_cp2,stop_cp2);
    cudaEventDestroy(start_cp2);
    cudaEventDestroy(stop_cp2);
    printf("\ntime taken by copy of a variable is  %f\n",elapsedTime_cp2);


cudaMemcpy(&pos,d_pos,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
printf("\nminimum index is %d\n",pos);
return 0;
}
```

how can i decrease total time taken by this code with any other option for performance.

Comment: What is the speed of the kernel which produces the contents of the device array relative to the copy operation? Is it faster or slower?

Comment: The code in its current form does not really make sense. So I assume that *before* you call `cudaMemcpy` in the loop, the kernel is launched (filling `dev_A` with new data each time) - is this correct?

Comment: Would it be possible to alternate the device array that will be updated?

Comment: ya i have a kernel that fills in dev_A array

Comment: actually my task is to find first index from 0 which contains 1 stored at this location in array A and this array is filled on GPU.i thought to launch a kernel and compute index on GPU using atomicMin operation then i copy that variable to the host which is taking same time as copying of array size =3000

Comment: That looks like a good first naive direct approach. You should try it, compare the execution time with the CPU (better if it's also parallelized in CPU) and then see if you are happy with the speed up. Then, will be time to decided if use shared memory (or any other more sofisticated technique) worth the effort.

Comment: @pQB what do you want to tell i am not getting it.i tried first copy to cpu then compute and see total time which is approx=4000*.02 here .02 is copy time using cudaMemcpy and second approach is launch kernel to do this computation using atomicMin taken .02 time and copy of single variable that is computed on gpu takes .02 same time as copy of array of size 3000.

Comment: Ops, according to your code I gathered that you didn't finish your implementation. In that case, I recommend you update your question at least with with the kernel call so we can figured out a bit more about the problem.

Comment: @pQB i got time like this Time taken by kernel is  0.046560

time taken by copy of an array is  0.037088

time taken by copy of a variable is  0.022592

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your kernel 4000 times on GPU, it might be needed to use Asynchronous execution on kernel via different streams. It might be quicker using cudaMemCpyAsync is a non-blocking function for the host (in the case that you are executing M times your kernel).

A quick introduction to stream and asynchronous execution:
https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-overlap-data-transfers-cuda-cc/

Streams and concurrency:
http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf

Hope this can help...

Comment: Therefore was my question if it's a possibility to alternate the device array where the kernels write to. If this isn't possible, maybe through some kind of an iterative dependency, your answer wouldn't be an option. If it is possible, of course this is a good way.

Comment: why single variable transfer time and array size 3000 transfer time is  approx same?